# Symbol not found: _NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey on iOS 6.1

Tags: codenameone

after a few months I'm updating my app with new features but when I tried it on my iPod 4th gen, it crashed.
Everything is well on Android 4.4 and on simulator.

The only answer I found is about Facebook SDK not supporting iOS 6 anymore: did you updated the FB SDK to 4? could this be related?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The current Facebook SDK is `3.14` you can use an older version and also use versioned builds to reproduce an old build exactly as it was.

Comment: Hi shai, I just downloaded the sources and tried to compile in Xcode with iOS 5 as deployment target(this should be your setting) and I receive an error: -fembed-bitcode is not supported on versions of iOS prior to 6.0.  Setting dep target to 6.1 give another error which seems to agree to the FB theory: ld: warning: object file (/Users/brx/Development/tmp/3d202468-c42d-4531-80ec-ef4cfa700194-1450711479700-sources/dist/IJobClock-src/libFBSDKCoreKit.a(FBSDKGraphRequestPiggybackManager.o)) was built for newer iOS version (7.0) than being linked (6.1)

Comment: You need to disable bitcode in the newest version of xcode. We use a slightly older version of xcode to remain compatible to the old VM for as long as possible.

Comment: ok, it builds but I still have crash on start: **dyld: Symbol not found: _NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/AC3FC878-2268-4E74-BC2B-E3F8C6AA5A65/IJobClock.app/IJobClock
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
 in /var/mobile/Applications/AC3FC878-2268-4E74-BC2B-E3F8C6AA5A65/IJobClock.app/IJobClock** Xcode shows a screen with some assembly code I really can't understand, too hard for my poor knowledge!

Comment: Shai, I solved setting the Foundation.framework to "Optional", is it possible to do it on your server?

Comment: I'm not sure what the implications of doing that would be. We can possibly add a hint to the build server but we need to research this further. Can you file an issue in github with a link to this discussion?